# How to capture Image from video after 1 second in Android Studio

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, timer

I am new to android and image processing. What I have done so far is to have a canny video (which runs alright)

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    Mat imgOriginal = inputFrame.rgba();
    Mat imgCanny = new Mat();
    Imgproc.Canny(imgOriginal, imgCanny, 70, 100);

    return (imgCanny);

}
```

and capture image on touching the screen. The image is then stored to a directory.(This also is running alright)

```
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    Log.i(TAG,"onTouch event");
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss");
    String currentDateAndTime = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());

    //String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/sample_picture_" + currentDateandTime + ".jpg";
    //String test = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getPath();
    final String fileName = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getPath() + "/sample_picture_" + currentDateAndTime + ".jpg";

    mOpenCvCameraView.takePicture(fileName);
    Toast.makeText(this, fileName + " saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return false;
}
```

What i am trying to achieve is:

To capture the image from the video after some timer or delay of one second and store it in the directory. I have no idea how to do this. I have tried Timer and countdown Timer inside OnCameraFrame by copying the code from Ontouch() and placed a timer for mOpenCvCameraView.takePicture(fileName);
but they didn't work for me.

**Edit:** I am trying to do something like this but it is not working in my case. I want to capture the image after 1 second time instead of OnTouch event. Any suggestions?

```
 new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss");
            String currentDateAndTime = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
            final String fileName = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getPath() + "/sample_picture_" + currentDateAndTime + ".jpg";

            mOpenCvCameraView.takePicture(fileName);
        }
    }, 0, 1000);
```